# COMException occurred: ErrorCode = -2146824070

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office, office-interop, error-code

I am using the Interop library for Word, and I am getting a COM Exception:

Message: "Type Mismatch"
ErrorCode: -2146824070
Source: "Microsoft Word"

The method throwing the error is:

```
object docStart = doc.Content.End - 1;
object docEnd = doc.Content.End;
object start = subDoc.Content.Start;
object end = subDoc.Content.End;

Word.Range rng = doc.Range(ref docStart, ref docEnd);
rng.FormattedText = subDoc.Range(ref start, ref end);
```

(Error is being thrown when it tries to set the FormattedText property.)

The locals when debugging are:

```
docStart: 0
docEnd: 1
start: 0
end: 10
```

I'm not sure what my issue is here. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Needs to be `rng.FormattedText = subDoc.Range(ref start, ref end).FormattedText;` You cannot set FormattedText to a range object...

Comment: Are `doc` and `subDoc` from the same instance of Word? You cannot assign a FormattedText from one instance of Word to another, they have to both be in the same instance (i.e. same `Application`).

Comment: I'm opening them both using the same application. The method I've posted is within a class that is being called for each document.

Answer (score 1):

I would debug by splitting the last line into 2 parts.

1. calling `subdoc.Range` (putting the reslt in a temp variable)
2. setting that to `rng.FormattedText`.

Check that #1 is actually doing what you expect.  My guess is that it won't be because `end` goes beyond `documentEnd`.

Comment: After implementing this check, I can not see any difference between the tempRng and rng.FormattedText types. They are both of type{System.__ComObject}

Answer (score 0):

The last line needs to be

```
rng.FormattedText = subDoc.Range(ref start, ref end).FormattedText;
```

I.e. you need to add `.FormattedText` to the end of the line.

You cannot set FormattedText to a range object, you can only set it to a formattedText object.

The fact that they are both of type System.__ComObject just means they are both wrapped in a RCW. The objects inside the wrappers are of different types.

Comment: I'm not able to get that working either... Still giving me a type mismatch